# Is the "2.5 answers per question" requirement mandatory?

Tags: discussion

On the [Area 51's Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) page, I read:

> **1.6 answer ratio**
>   Okay – 2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. **On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.**

In Music Fans, a majority of questions are ID, and in these questions, only one answer - the good one - is necessary. It would mean that non ID questions will need 4, 5 answers to reach the 2.5 answers per question average.

I understand the other goals that are signs of healthy activity, but what about that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that everyone needs to remember is: Every site is different. No matter what, Music Fans will never have the answers per question rate that Worldbuilding or Programing Puzzles and Code Golf have. Many graduated sites have answer ratios even lower than 1.6.

However, that doesn't mean that we can't try and do better.

The first thing to remember is that we are always looking for quality answers that are detailed and well written. Getting a bunch of mediocre answers just to pad our statistics is not going to help the site.

There are two things that everyone can do. The first is, take the time to write your own answers. If nobody is taking the time to write answers, there won't be any. The second is, vote on questions and answers. The reputation that users get from votes is one of the things that keeps other users engaged in the site.

Comment: I'd just like to add quantity does not equal quality. Getting the stat up alone won't mean much if the answers are very low in quality and get removed or ignored.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the answer per question average was a mandatory requirement.